# Loop/Cycle detection in a linked list in Java

Tags: java, loops, linked-list, nodes

Question:
Given a circular linked llist, implement an algorithm that returns the node at the beginning of the loop.

I am not requesting an answer to this problem!

I know there are some loop detection algorithms involving two pointers moving at different speeds, and I already know some answers to this question.

However, what I am wondering about is that when I first attempted to solve this question, I approached in this way:

```
LinkedListNode loopExists(LinkedListNode node) {
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    while(node != null) {
        if(hs.contains(node))
            return node;
        else
            hs.add(node);
        node = node.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am curious because there is no answer that's like what I posted above.

The question is asking for the node at the beginning of the loop.

If I iterate through the linked list checking each node (not node.data) and if I find the same node again, I am assuming that's the node at the beginning of the loop.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Please let me know if there is anything I'm misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Such a question belongs more to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How do you define the beginning of the loop? It could be any node in the loop, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: A loop has no "beginning".

Comment: Input: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> C
Output: C
I meant the beginning and the end of the of loop (the duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, we can have multiple solution. And, if solution isn't available, then that doesn't mean that can't be solution.

For example, another solution could be, we can have `flag` attribute in each node and marked `checked` when visited. In this case, if same node repeated again, then we can check for `flag` attribute and detect loop.

Now, in your case, you are using unnecessary memory to store node object, which can be solved without storing node object by running a loop.

Comment: I agree with Ravi's comment on memory: the HashSet will temporarily take up memory roughly proportional to your list size. But it's a very straightforward and readable implementation, nothing wrong with it. The two pointers with different speeds take constant memory (2 pointers), but the resulting code is hardly readable (if you don't happen to know the algorithm). And I'd strongly discourage introducing a 'flag' field. A method like loopExists() should not have to change any state of the argument LinkedList.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate more on the point that my solution is using unnecessary memory to store node object? I am a newbie and I cannot quite understand it here yet I have read about memory before :(

Comment: @NomaCitzen Ok, first of all you are creating an instance of `HashSet`, which going to take some memory. right ? Now, once you start you loop, in each iteration, you are going to store the reference of each node which will keep on growing until you find the loop.

Comment: @NomaCitzen you need to clarify your doubt and once you got the answer. You need to make practice of accepting it.